# Mocking a REST Datasource in a Model TestCase for CakePHP

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, rest, cakephp, datasource

I am using the [CakePHP-ReST-DataSource-Plugin](https://github.com/nojimage/CakePHP-ReST-DataSource-Plugin) Datasource for hitting a RESTful service in my model. This implies that the models will not have a database connection.

I have successfully accessed the services and would now like to write unit tests for the models. This is proving to be a daunting task since I cannot succeed to mock the datasource so that I do not hit the actual remote Service but rather return expected results for the tests.

```
<?php

    App::uses('KnowledgePoint', 'Model');

    class KnowledgePointTest extends CakeTestCase{
    public $fixtures = array('app.knowledgepoint');
    public $useDbConfig = 'RestTest';
    private $KnowledgePoint;


    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->KnowledgePoint = ClassRegistry::init('KnowledgePoint');

        /**
        * This is the confusing part. How would I mock the datasource 
        so that I can mock the request method which returns the data 
        from the api?
        */
        $this->KnowledgePoint->DataSource = $this->getMockForModel(
            'RestSource',array('request'));
    }

    public function tearDown() {
      parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to mock the datasource and stub the request method to return data that would normally be returned from the remote service.

Kind regards,

Roland

Comment: Check how the core is doing it: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.6/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Model/Datasource/DataSourceTest.php#L110**

Comment: I tried mocking it the way the core does, but I keep getting the error that the TestSource Mock was not found.

Comment: And does the core test fail as well?

Comment: The core test also fails with the same problem, MissingDatasourceException.

Comment: I see, it looks like this test is actually not included in the testsuite... not creating an additional connection should theoretically work I guess, I'll add an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocking the model and its `getDataSource()` method so that it returns your mocked datasource should theoretically work. Here's an example

```
App::uses('RestSource', 'Rest.Model/Datasource');

$DataSource = $this->getMock('RestSource', array('request'), array(array()));
$DataSource
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('request')
    ->will($this->returnValue('some custom return value'));

$Model = $this->getMockForModel('KnowledgePoint', array('getDataSource'));
$Model
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getDataSource')
    ->will($this->returnValue($DataSource));

$Model->save(/* ... */);
```

In case you are wondering about the `array(array())` for the datasource mock, this is required as the `RestSource` constructor doesn't supply a default value for the first argument (unlike the parent constructor).

Comment: Have successfully implemented this solution to avoid hitting the remote Service. Thanks for your help.